# Checking the biconnectivity of a biconnected graph with a vertex removed

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

If I have a biconnected graph and I remove a vertex (without forgetting which vertex was removed and which vertices it was adjacent to), is there an way to check the biconnectivity of the resulting graph that is easier than checking the biconnectivity of an arbitrary graph? E.g., is there a method that in the best case requires only local examination (perhaps some property of the adjacent vertices)?

Comment: I don't think there can be a purely local algorithm; consider a graph which is basically two separate graphs, connected with two widely-separated bridges. Removing a node to destroy one of the bridges doesn't give any obvious way to find that there's only one other bridge at the far end of the graph.

That said, there are clearly some shortcuts. For example, if the subgraph consisting only of the removed node's neighbors is still 2-connected, then the entire graph is as well.

Comment: That shortcut you mentioned is exactly the sort of thing I'm after. I do realize that no algorithm could be local in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is 3-connectivity checking (if you remove any vertex from a 3-connected graph it produces another 3-connected or a biconnected graph. It kind of works like bi-connectivity and simple connectivity, in fact you can generalize this principal to k-connectivity).

An efficient method (linear time) to check 3-connectivity can be derived from the Tarjan-Hopcroft algorithm. This method splits a 2-connected graph into a 3-conncted multigraph. If the algorithm doesn't split the graph it means that the graph is already 3-connected.

However I have to warn you, the literature around this algorithm is quite complicated and is not the best one to start learning about graph analysis algorithms.